# fetch POST returns only _id object in Express API server React FrontEnd

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I'm trying to make a React-Node.js application for practice. I encountered an problem in sending POST request. When I fetch POST request in App.js, it returns only id. I expected it to return 3 more values.

Current object

`{ _id: 5a046d52bb5d37063b3c8b21 }`

Ideal object

`{_id: "59e9fed60fe8bf0d7fd4ac6e", name: "recipe1", ingredients: "apple", descriptions: "cut an apple"}`

How should I add values to req.body correctly?  I referred this solution [Post an object with fetch using react js and express API server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288147/post-an-object-with-fetch-using-react-js-and-express-api-server) but it didn't work with my app.

index.js (node.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

 // Serve static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

var db

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect
('mongodb://Recipe:recipebox@ds125914.mlab.com:25914/ayumi', (err, database) => {
 if (err) return console.log(err)
 db = database
 app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('listening on 8080')
 })
 })

 app.get('/api', (req,res)=> {
     db.collection('recipe').find().toArray((err, results) => {
     if(err) return console.log("no recipe");
         res.json(results);
     })
 })

 app.post('/recipe', (req,res)=>{
     db.collection('recipe').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
     if(err) return console.log(err);
          console.log(req.body)
    console.log('save to database');
    res.redirect('/');
})
})
```

App.js (react)

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch('/recipe', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({
           name: this.refs.name.value,
           ingredients: this.refs.ingredients.value,
           descriptions: this.refs.descriptions.value
       }),
       headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
       })
  .then((res)=> {
      return res.json()
  })
  .then((body)=>{
      console.log("body" + body)
      console.log("result" + this.refs.name.value)
  })
}

render() {

return (
  <div className="App">
  <h1>Recipe List</h1>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" ref="name" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="ingredients" ref="ingredients" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="descriptions" ref="descriptions" />
  <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
  </div>
  )
}
```

}

export default App;

Comment: I'm surprised you get *anything* back considering the POST method server-side just ends in a redirect and never uses the `result` value (which likely contains your freshly created data object). Do you see values being written into the database?

Comment: Value is not added. Each object contains only id like ```{"_id":"5a0472c56f37cb06a4c8f54c"}]```

Comment: But everytime you add a recipe, there is a new entry in the `recipe` collection with just the `_id` field set, correct?

Comment: What does the `console.log(req.body)` from within `app.post` show?

Comment: It showed `listening on 8080
{ _id: 5a0472c56f37cb06a4c8f54c }
save to database`

Comment: So then your `req.body` object only contains an `_id` field.. which is odd since it's the one field you're *not* passing during the `fetch` call. You confirm the code that gave you this log is the one you've posted above? It's still `console.log(req.body)`, and not `console.log(result)`, correct?

Comment: I'll just write up an answer with the things I would change in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side changes:

```
app.post('/recipe', (req, res) => {
  // log the body of the request, to make sure data is properly passed
  console.log(req.body);
  // use mongodb's insertOne instead of the deprecated save
  db.collection('recipe').insertOne(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    // log the result of db insertion
    console.log(result);
    console.log('saved to database');
    // send the freshly saved record back to the front-end
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

Front-end changes:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // add state to hold recipe returned from POST call
    this.state = {
      recipe: null,
      name: '',
      ingredients: '',
      descriptions: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, ingredients, descriptions } = this.state;
    fetch('/recipe', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        ingredients,
        descriptions
      }),
      headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
    })
    // when call completes, it should return the newly created recipe object
    // as it was saved in the DB - just store it into state
    .then((recipe)=> {
      this.setState({recipe});
    });
    // TODO: handle error case
  }

  render() {
    // added a paragraph tag to display the ID of the freshly created recipe
    // it's only displayed if recipe is not null or undefined
    // further changes: turning inputs into controlled inputs
    const { name, ingredients, descriptions } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Recipe List</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            value={name}
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
            placeholder="name" />
          <input
            value={ingredients}
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ ingredients: e.target.value })}                
            placeholder="ingredients" />
          <input
            value={descriptions}
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ descriptions: e.target.value })}
            placeholder="descriptions" />
          <input type="submit"/>
          { recipe &&
            <p>Saved ID: {this.state.recipe._id}</p>
          }
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Further changes: turned all three text inputs into controlled inputs (values of all 3 fields are tracked in state, and passed to `fetch` when the form is submitted).

Comment: Thank you so much for answer! I tried it, but it didn't add any data apart from _id. The result in Terminal : `CommandResult {
  result: 
   { n: 1,
     opTime: { ts: [Object], t: 2 },
     electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000002,
     ok: 1 },
  connection: 
   Connection {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        timeout: [Object],
        parseError: [Object] }, .....`

Comment: @aaayumi What is the output of `console.log(req.body)` (at the beginning of `app.post('/recipe', ...)`)?

Comment: @aaayumi well then that's where your problem is, somehow you're passing empty/no data, so that explains why the objects in the DB have no data except for the `_id`, which is created automatically by the DB.

Comment: @aaayumi In your `handleSubmit` method in the client, try logging one (or all) of the three values you're attempting to pass, i.e. `console.log(this.refs.name.value)`. Put that log before the `fetch` call.

Comment: @aaayumi I've updated my answer to turn all 3 inputs into controlled inputs as I suspect the issue might be with using refs. Changes were made on the front-end side only.

Comment: I tried your new solution. Still it prints out `{}`. However `handleSubmit` can print each value input now. I think I need to modify `fetch`..

Comment: @aaayumi Your use of `fetch` looks fine to me. Sorry, I'm running out of ideas here... Have you tried sending a request manually to your API with a tool like Postman? It would be nice to be able to isolate the issue into either the client or the server. Another idea would be to look at the XHR request (issued through `fetch`) in the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I tried ` .then((recipe)=> {
       console.log(recipe)
      });` and it printed out `Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/recipe", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}` there is no data inside in recipe object. I suppose this is an issue?